# php XCRUD verification key is out of date

Tags: php, verification

Somebody here using xcrud php framework Im currently encountering the error below:

The verification key is out of date
This means that your browser cached a previous version of this page with an old key (for security reasons the verification key is generated every request)
Why? Maybe you pressed the back button in your browser or opened a bookmark from last session. 
Just reload the page, nothing happened :)

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: the error is the message below the verification key is out of date. I refresh my page still loads the same error message I inspect element nothing wrong in the network and console searched on the xcrud documentation saying its SESSION related Im using codeigniter and xcrud as a crud plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same xCrud problem: "The verification key is out of date... ".
I was using:
- xCrud 1.6.26
- Code Igniter 3.1.0
- wamp 2.5 (windows).
After trying many work around with no result, **i finnally found a solution using xCrud 1.6.26 with CodeIgniter 2.2.6.**
**Now xCrud works perfectly.**
The problem was linked to session managment. The CodeIgniter documentation say that session library had been completely rewriten into CodeIgniter  3.0. 
I think that causes the probleme with xCrud.